# https server on esp32 wrover cam module

Tags: https, esp32, spiffs

I want to create a https server in ESP32 wrover module. I have googled and created the below code.

`

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h> 
#include <HTTPSServer.hpp> 
#include <SSLCert.hpp> 
#include <FS.h> 
#include <LittleFS.h> 
#include <SPIFFS.h>

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid = "Buffalo-G-0238";
const char* password = "xvpi4w8km4bhr";

// The HTTPS Server comes in a separate namespace. For easier use, include it here.
using namespace httpsserver;

#define FORMAT_LITTLEFS_IF_FAILED true

// Create an SSL certificate object
SSLCert cert;

void setup() {
// Connect to Wi-Fi
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
delay(1000);
Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
}
Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

// Print the IP address
Serial.print("IP Address: ");
Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
ESP.restart();
}

LittleFS.begin("spiffs");

File certFile = LittleFS.open("/data/server.pem", "r");
if (!certFile) {
Serial.println("Failed to open cert file");
return;
}

File privateKeyFile = LittleFS.open("/data/server.key", "r");
if (!privateKeyFile) {
Serial.println("Failed to open private key file");
return;
}

// Create the SSL certificate
const uint16_t certSize = certFile.size();
unsigned char certData\[certSize\];
certFile.read(certData, certSize);
cert.setCert(certData, certSize);

const uint16_t prikeySize = privateKeyFile.size();
unsigned char prikeyData\[prikeySize\];
certFile.read(prikeyData, prikeySize);
cert.setPK(prikeyData, prikeySize);

// Create an SSL-enabled server that uses the certificate
HTTPSServer secureServer = HTTPSServer(&cert);

// Add a GET endpoint for the root URL ("/")
ResourceNode\* nodeRoot = new ResourceNode("/", "GET", \[\](HTTPRequest\* req, HTTPResponse\* res) {
if (req && res) {  // Check for null pointers
res-\>setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
res-\>println("\<!DOCTYPE html\>\<html\>\<body\><h1>Hello, world!</h1>\</body\>\</html\>");
}
});

secureServer.registerNode(nodeRoot);

// Start the server
secureServer.start();

if (secureServer.isRunning()) {
Serial.println("Server ready.");
}

}

void loop() { // Nothing }
```

Program download is success. But I am getting below error after reset.
`

```
E (1559) SPIFFS: mount failed, -10025 
E (16717) esp_littlefs: ./components/esp_littlefs/src/littlefs/lfs.c:1347:error: Corrupted dir pair at {0x0, 0x1}
E (16718) esp_littlefs: mount failed,  (-84)
E (16721) esp_littlefs: Failed to initialize LittleFS
```

I dont know what causing the problem. I am having server.key and server.pem files in the sketch/data folder.

Please help me with this problem.

I am stucking in this more than a week.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried in googling and modified here and there but still i am not getting the results.

Comment: Why are you initializing both SPIFFS and LittleFS?

Comment: @romkey At first I didn't initialize SPIFFS. when it is not working i used SPIFFS for testing. But still i have the same problem.

Comment: Instead of using spiff or little fs you can keep cert and key in arduino sketch